# make Java GUI with many interactive image buttons

Tags: java, image, user-interface, embedded

I am attempting to create a a java GUI for use on Zedboard with the 7" touchscreen display. The GUI I am creating is supposed to mimic exactly (though scaled down) a physical console with many interactive buttons.

My question is what would be the best method in making the buttons interactive, my first thought was to cut out the buttons of the console and have each one a separate image that can be set as interactive, but I feel there may be another simpler method.

Thanks

LDY

Comment: Are you using Swing? AWT? JavaFX? Android? Something else? What happened when you tried the image approach? Why does that seem too complicated to you?

Comment: Swing is my current approach, it is not necessarily to complicated just curious of other approaches to possibly save time (and avoid trimming image with my shoddy paint skills). I am slightly worried about swing running on the embedded environment okay, but the board is running Linux and once the bitmapping is all taken care of I am hopeful it will be fine.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by 'make the buttons interactive'?

Comment: awt is used also for action listener I should also mention. By interactive I mean the touchscreen has a GUI with an image on a physical console that has many buttons, the GUI will read touches of each button. Each physical button will be turned into a Jbutton.

Comment: The best method would be use JavaFX to create a GUI. In case you use Swing, the mouse click event corresponds to a touch event. So just implement the action listener for each JButton.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with JavaFX but I am not opposed to using it by any means if it is the better options, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the console mimicking, you could take an image of the entire console and then listen to touch event at specific points in the image which corresponds to a button. Based on where the touch event occurs, you could do different actions.

For this you need to get the coordinates of the touch event and check if it corresponds to any of the buttons on the console.